# Хаки к играм и их создание

Tags: разработка-игр, взлом

Возник такой вопрос, ответ на который хочется уточнить. Иногда можно встретить различные "хаки" к играм, к примеру в warcraft 3/dota пишут различные maphack: запускаем приложение и оно, к примеру, показывает в цифрах скорость регенерации health points, открывает всю карту и т.п.

В Call Of Duty : Modern Warfare 3 можно запустить приложение и сделать inject dll файла в запущенных экзэшник игры, после чего бот ходит и стреляет за тебя, в смысле стоит лишь, чтобы враг попал в область видимости - бот сразу же точно сам стреляет и убивает.

Почему возник вопрос... Я-то в игры играю редко, но само то, как делаются такие хаки - стало интересно, задумался... Как это они так делают? Что ли как-то модифицируют какие-то игровые значения или что? Reverse Engineering может быть?

Допустим, как в Modern Warfare 3 выделяет оппонента издалека красным квадратом - как? Как программа знает об этом? И что вообще даст inject dll файла?

А как заставляет бота стрелять автоматически..

Сложно ли это и что за сферы нужно учить? (может кому-то вопрос покажется легким или даже тупым, но я, к сожалению, не профи в этом деле, поэтому хотел бы задать такой вот вопрос)

Comment: >> И что вообще даст inject dll файла

единое адрессное пространство. Можно читать и записывать в память свои значения

Comment: А, ясно, но как эти функции выполняются? Т.е. что происходит при самом инжекте библиотеки? Ведь те функции, которые там написаны, не будут произвольно вызываться из программы, которая уже написана или что?

Comment: P.S.: А кто-то этим вообще когда-то занимался (про что я спрашиваю), если да, то сложно ли это и знает ли кто подходящую литературу? Т.к. я разве что 1 книгу знаю по reverse engineering на эту тему.

Comment: Если бы мне попался тот, кто делает хаки на игры - то я бы руки ему поотбивал. Так что, если вы собрались этим заниматься, то не ищите со мной встречи ))) Я не такой уж геймер, но если я плачу за игрушку, то хочу наслаждаться игрой честной. Если бы вы сели играть в карты, и за вашим столом сидел шулер, который знал все ваши карты, то какие бы эмоции он у вас вызвал?

Comment: Ну меня больше возмущает то, что те, кто пишут хаки на игры выставляют их в паблик.Я считаю, что если им хватило знаний написать такой хак, то сами может пусть и пользуются (это как преимущество в том, что они вместо других геймеров учились вместо игр,а теперь эти знания могут применить, в частности таким путем). Но выкладывать в паблик - не хорошо... Да и к тому же защита от хаков это ведь задача разработчиков онлайн-платформы ;)  И обычно такие вот "хакеры" всёравно много в игры не играют, так что от того, что они одну игру в неделю будут с хаком на первых порах играть - не сыграет ничего =

Comment: p.s.: сам в игры играю редко, но когда играл в МВ3, то хак когда использовал - заканчивал со счетом, к примеру, 40\42 (убийства\смерти). Так что я использовал хак не бездумно, а, скажем, периодически). Но те, что школьники.. которые скачали хак и играют со счетом 100\2 - раздражает конечно.. Обычно против таких я хак и включаю, т.к. их едва убивают заядлые геймеры.

Comment: Ну вот началась сантабарбара. А всё потому, что вопрос идиотский. И, кстати, адресное пространство процесса прекрасно читается без внедрения.

Comment: (Продолжая Санта-Барбару) Если уж кому руки отбивать — так тем игроделам, кто позволяет хакам существовать. Существовать читам позволяет только подход «мы тут тебе передаем координаты, но, вообще-то, они за стеной, так что ты их знать не должен» или «мы от тебя приняли обновление и поверим что ты за секунду ушел на километр.» Это, извините, в духе как если в форме логина было бы `if (password.value == "secret") { location.redirect("/secretadminlocation/"); } else { alert("Неправильный пароль"); }`. За последнее ругают веб-макак, а почему такие двойные стандарты к первому?

Comment: Санта-Барбар (серия №333)

@drdaeman , точно! А вор-форточник теперь может оправдываться в суде, мол какого хрена строители не зашили форточку стальным листом. И под суд этих строителей, с конфискацией имущества по этапу ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Допустим, как в Modern Warfare 3 выделяет оппонента издалека красным квадратом - как?

Если очень примитивно, то на карте вы расположены с определенными координатами. Между машинами играющих идет постоянный обмен пакетами, в которых содержаться координаты всех игроков. Именно поэтому вы и видите или не видите каждого игрока в определенный промежуток времени. Но эти координаты предназначены в первую очередь для машины, которая должна знать, где "отрисовать" того или иного игрока. Хак перехватывает эти пакеты и "рассказывает" вам где кто находится, даже если он не в поле вашего зрения. А подсветить красным квадратиком - уже дело техники ))

Comment: Т.е. фактически суть в том, что при помощи реверсинга хакер узнает что под какими значениями как перехватывать, а потом при помощи инжекта dll эти функции рисуют квадраты - что-то вроде того?

Comment: Ну, образно говоря, да.

Comment: Т.е. допустим хакер отсниффал пакет, в пакете были координаты, мои, а также противников, потом он заинжектил свой код в процесс (подробности опускаю, т.к. не знаю как это происходит) и уже тот его код, который записан в билблиотеке - расчитывает дистанцию (на основе координат, вычитает их например), а затем это значение дистанции (хранящееся в переменной) записывает в функцию отрисовки прямоугольника (где значение этой переменной есть что-то вроде масштаба), таким образом дальние объекты будут в маленьких прямоугольниках, а ближние - реального размера.

Answer (score 1):

Сильно упрощенно пример отрисовки прямоугольника можно представить следующим образом. Исходный код игры:

```
class GlobalContext {
    static GameDev.IGame Game = new GameDev.Game();
    // .....
}
```

Злоумышленник разрабатывает следующий код:

```
namespace GameHack {
    // наследуемся от класса разработчика игры
    class Game : GameDev.Game {
        protected override DrawPlayer(PlayerInfo pi) {
            // рисуем все что было раньше
            base(pi);
            // получаем координаты прямоугольника, ограничивающего модель игрока
            Coordinates border = this.GetPlayerBorderRectangle(pi);
            // рисуем закрашенный прямоугольник по этим координатам
            this.DrawBar(border, Color.Red);
        }
    }
}
```

И при inject dll внедряет в программу этот код и выполняет дополнительно следующий:

```
GlobalContext.Game = new GameHack.Game();
```

Таким образом при отрисовке изобретать велосипед не обязательно, а можно использовать уже готовую функциональность игры. Злоумышленнику достаточно лишь добавить небольшой штрих в урпавлении программой. В моем примере для создания этого штриха использовался шаблон проектирования декоратор.

Кстати мультиплеер в МВ2 был реализован на .NET и за него отвечал интерфейс IWNet. "Сторонние разработчики" создали свою реализацию интерфейса IWNet и назвали ее AlterIWNet. Альтернативный мультиплеер AlterIWNet - пример высокоуровневого хака игры :). Ссылку дать не могу, т.к. на данный момент насколько я понял этот проект прекратил свое существование.